# AsusGeForce GTX 970 installation crash

Tags: 14.04, boot, nvidia, graphics, gpu

I have bought 6 month ago this GPU: https://www.asus.com/uk/Graphics-Cards/STRIXGTX970DC2OC4GD5/

I flashed my USB stick with Ubuntu 16.10, 16.04, 14.04 but every times I boot it through the BIOS of my motherboard. The screen goes black, then a `_` flash, quickly followed by a thin line of colour and then monitor does not recognise any input and everything remains black.

I know that the card runs perfectly on Windows as I was using it on another machine.

Do you know if there is any way to fix this problem ?

Comment: Boot with `nomodeset`, then install Nvidia drivers from Ubuntu repos.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)